# Channels with Composer Multiorg setup

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have just defined my Fabric network, having **3 orgs** as Org1, Org2, and Org3. **Org1 and Org2** are a part of a **channel1** and **Org3 and Org1** connected on **channel2**.

The intent is not to replicate the data to an org's peer who isn't a part of the transaction.

What should be the **connection profile for the composer application of Org1** as it's a part of two channels? It might have to perfom certain transaction/trade with either Org2 or Org3 based on some conditions.

Is there anyway to achieve this with composer or should I just use vanilla Fabric and chaincode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This extract from a [previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50252488/hyperledger-composer-for-enterprise/50254624#50254624) should help:

"Composer connects with Fabric using Business Network Cards, and these contain credentials and a Connection Profile. The connection profile contains definitions of the 'services' on the Fabric, and so it is possible to define specific Peers within the card.

Regarding channels - it is again the Connection Profile that determines the Channel used, and at the moment only one channel is supported per Card. Multiple cards can be used but disconnect/switch/re-connect might not be practical or desirable in some cases. There is a way to connect to a different Business Network on a different Channel covered in this tutorial, but again it might not be suitable for all cases.

There is an [outstanding issue on GitHub](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/2103) for using Composer for multi-channel, so you can leave a comment or +1 on it - particularly if you have a good use case for multi-channel.

Many people are thinking of and using channels as a security feature, but Composer ACLs might solve that issue in some cases. Similarly the upcoming sidedb feature in Fabric might offer security instead of separate channels."

Comment: Thanks for answering. Sidedb seems to be an easier solution to implement the privacy. Do you any clue by when sidedb feature can be supported by the composer? The fabric would have it from 1.2. Haven't found any pointers for Composer.

Comment: Can Sidedb really replace the need for channels? As channels do make sure that the authorized peers get to persist the data which would be available for all the peers over that channel, forever. But sidedb persists really sensitive data only for the configured number of blocks(blockToLive)