# Configuring Hyperledger Fabric for a Production Environment

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, production-environment, hyperledger-composer

I am new to Hyperledger and am exploring its possibilities. The tutorials seem to be focused on creating business networks rather than configuring Hyperledger Fabric itself. Are fabric-dev-servers and fabric-samples, which are downloaded in the initial tutorials, fit for a production environment?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

the Fabric-dev-servers (Composer) and `Fabric-samples` (Hyperledger Fabric) - are samples or a development setup (the clue is in the name) to help developers (and other roles like architects, consultants etc) get going quickly with building blockchain solutions.

On production question - see answers in this Stack Overflow -> [Hyperledger composer for enterprise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50252488/hyperledger-composer-for-enterprise/50254624#50254624)

Obviously when building/architecting/deploying a production scale blockchain network between multiple organisations/parties/members, there are MANY considerations. The Composer business networks that is/are installed to the peers in a Fabric network are self-contained, smart contracts complete with model definitions, security rules, transaction logic and queries/indexes and are deployed as 'code', to be executed on a running blockchain network.

happy exploring !