# Hyperledger Fabric: UI for first-network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am quite new to Hyperledger Blockchain and have started with exploring 2 sample codes.

(1) https://medium.freecodecamp.org/ultimate-end-to-end-tutorial-to-create-an-application-on-blockchain-using-hyperledger-3a83a80cbc71  - where creating an application using hyperledger was taught - through creating .bna, .card files, deploying them etc. Also saw that an Angular extension is supported, giving the UI.

(2) Classic first-network http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/build_network.html - where chaincode was deployed etc.

My question is, how can I get a UI for (2),like I did in (1)? It was quite convenient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the First tutorial, you used Hyperledger Composer to create a BNA which is a friendly way to create chaincode, and there is an Angular Application generator included.

In the second you directly installed some chaincode on to Fabric without a UI (and without using Composer.  In this case you would have to write the UI yourself.  In the first example you can build your own app by extending the generated app.

Composer is a tool that makes it easy and fast to create chaincode and applications to run on Fabric.  If you don't use Composer you do have some more flexibility, but you have to do more work yourself.

Comment: So smart contracts (or chaincode) were the statements we wrote in the .js file? And .acl files controls access? Do you have some references for creating multihosts on composer? Or creating multiple channels on composer? Or similar features that we can commonly see on fabric?

Comment: For Composer, the SmartContract includes all the elements in the BNA.  (model, js, acl, queries).  There is a MultiOrg tutorial on the Composer documentation - it simulates MultiOrg on a single computer.  https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org

Comment: Thanks so much! Is the provision of making multiple channels supported on composer now?

Comment: Regarding Channels - please see this previous answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50252488/hyperledger-composer-for-enterprise/50254624#50254624